# i create one map activity using google api but when i start my app it shows the default location not current

Tags: android

i create one map activity using google api
but when i start my app it shows the default location but not that location when currently m present after enabling gps

MapsActivity

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getName();
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        initClient();
    }

    private void initClient() {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).setInterval(10 * 1000).setFastestInterval(1 * 1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location service is connected");
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

        if (location == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "No location found,Requesting for location update");
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
        }
        else
        {


            handleLocation(location);
        }
    }


    private void handleLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
        double latitude=location.getLatitude();
        double longitude=location.getLongitude();

        LatLng currentLatLng=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);


        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(currentLatLng).title("I am Here.").snippet("Consider U R Located");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLatLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Google Api Client is Suspended,Please Connect It");

    }



    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connection has failed with code" + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleLocation(location);


    }


}
```

menifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.javapapers.currentlocationinmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <!--<intent-filter>-->
                <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->

                <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
            <!--</intent-filter>-->
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>



        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

i already add api key in google_maps_api.xml

Comment: you can pass fix lat ang lag so you can find fix location see  LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151); change it with your location.i think you can get always sydney in your map

Comment: but if i give fix latitude and longitude then it will show that location always na,but i want current location where i have present

Comment: wait i will post my code

Answer (score 0):

Call this method in onCreate()

```
 private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {


         mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude())).title("It's Me!"));
       }
      });

        }
    }
}
```

Refer here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intro#sample_code

**If the above doesn't work out try using LocationManager.**

```
LocationManager locationManager = LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Creating an empty criteria object
 Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 
// Getting the name of the provider that meets the criteria 
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
long c = location.getLatitude();
long d = location.getLongitude();
```

And using the latitude and longitude values in your onLocationChangedListener!

Comment: "setOnMyLocationChangeListener"

Comment: this method is depricated

Answer (score 0):

this because you have added marker at this default sydney location please get your current latlng and add your marker at your current location.

```js
 LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
```

use this **LocationService.class** to get your current location

```js
public class LocationService extends Service {

    private static final int LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2 * 1000;
    private static final int LOCATION_UPDATE_DISTANCE = 5;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private LocationUpdatesListener mLocationUpdatesListener;
    private Context mContext;
    public static double mLatitude = 0.0;
    public static double mLongitude = 0.0;
    public static boolean socketConnected=false;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocationUpdatesListener = new LocationUpdatesListener();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                        0, mLocationUpdatesListener);
            }
            if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,
                        0, mLocationUpdatesListener);
            }

        }
        mCountDowntimer.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationUpdatesListener);
        }

    }

    public class LocationUpdatesListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {

            if (null != location) {
           
            mLatitude=location.getLatitude();
                mLongitude=location.getLongitude();
            }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps not working",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }
    }


}
```

and than after starting service at in just add

```js
LatLng sydney = new LatLng(LocationService.mLatitude, LocationService.mLongitude);
```

also add this permission to manifest

```js
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

and this service tag

```js
<service
            android:name=".LocationService"
            android:enabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

here you can do like this see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER

```
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you import any google map sample then you will get their own location lat and long.

You need to add your own location lat and long so you can see marker over there.

If you will add  `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`
then you can see current location symbol(icon) at map screen and click on that you will move to current location with blue marker(google default).

FYI :https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location